# Building a mean-variance frontier with 15 stocks without fPortfolio package

Tags: r, finance, r-portfolioanalytics

I could obtain the daily returns, but can't get any further. With the following code.

```
# create list of stock tickers – replace the tickers here with those you want to use in your portfolio

TickerList <- c("T", "GOOG", "CSCO", "MSFT", "JNPR", "AAPL", "AMZN", "GOOGL", "JNJ", "FB", "V", "HD", "VZ", "MA", "INTC")

# read closing prices from Yahoo keeping only the closing prices

ClosingPricesRead <- NULL
for (Ticker in TickerList)
  ClosingPricesRead <- cbind(ClosingPricesRead,
                             getSymbols.yahoo(Ticker,
                                              from="2016-12-31",
                                              to="2019-12-31",
                                              verbose=FALSE,
                                              auto.assign=FALSE)[,4]) # [,6] = keep the adjusted prices

# keep only the dates that have closing prices for all tickers

ClosingPrices <- ClosingPricesRead[apply(ClosingPricesRead,1,function(x) all(!is.na(x))),]

# convert prices to daily returns

returns <- as.timeSeries((tail(ClosingPrices,-1) / as.numeric(head(ClosingPrices,-1)))-1)
```

## Build the Mean-Variance Frontier.

I have been struggling to do this because I can't use the fPortafolio package.
Also I need help to get the Capital Market Line (considering a free risk asset from the federal reserve.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to next find the volatility, mean return and correlations. This is not as trivial as it sounds because there isn't a right answer for selecting the right time frame. You'll also need to make sure your return calculation is right. That is, total return or price return.

After this you need to find an optimizer that can be used to construct the optimal portfolio at each risk level. The most efficient way to do this is to start with the highest risk, highest return point on the efficient frontier. Then seed the algorithm with the previous portfolio as you work your way down. If your most volatile stock does not have the highest return you'll have to deal with that additional complication.

After this is finding the capital allocation line. The first problem is deciding which asset to use. Probably the best way to make this selection is to be consistent with the time frame you selected for your vol and return calculation. One you have your expected return for the risk free asset you need to find the optima market portfolio. This should be relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If your data is ready, just start playing around with the `package`. Building frontiers looks like this:</s>

```
library(fPortfolio)

myData <- as.timeSeries(myData)  # Get the data in the right format

mySpec <- portfolioSpec()  # This depends on the problem at hand
setNFrontierPoints(mySpec) <- 20  # for the chart
longFrontier <- portfolioFrontier(myData, mySpec)  # Default frontier

frontierPlot(longFrontier)  # This will create a chart
```

There are a lot other options available. For more details, please follow the examples [here](https://www.rmetrics.org/ebooks-portfolio), ch. 18.

Just realized you said **without fPortfolio** :

Here's a [good source](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfoliotheorynoshortsalesslides.pdf) if you're interested in solving the optimization problem yourself. The problem is quite straightforward to set up and resolve using some quadratic programming [optimization package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) such as `quadprog`.